# Abstract common function behavior into higher order function

Tags: javascript

I have three pretty similar functions:

```
//for context there is also this part:
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(["#000000", "#ffffff"]);
// but the three functions start here:

 function updateColor(index, color) {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    newColors[index] = color;
    setColors(newColors);
  }

  function deleteColor(index) {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    newColors.splice(index, 1);
    setColors(newColors);
  }

  function duplicateColor(index) {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    newColors.splice(index, 0, newColors[index]);
    setColors(newColors);
  }
```

As you can see the first and third line of each of these are identical. Is there some method by which I can create a function that takes the middle line as a callback function and reproduces the first and third.

Something like:

```
const updateColor = functionMaker((index, color) => newColors[index]);
const deleteColor = functionMaker((index) => newColors.splice(index, 1));
```

I can't quite get my head around how I would support different arguments for each, as in my example above.

Comment: Your second and third function only have `index` as argument. What will `colors` be inside of them then?

Comment: `colors` is available from outside the scope of these function due to a closure.

Comment: Then why does the first need a second argument?

Comment: Note pluralization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) as shown below. However, please note that this example is not well-encapsulated, and frankly removing those two lines of code might not be worth creating the abstraction.

```
function modifyColor(strategy) {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    strategy(newColors);
    setColors(newColors);
}

 function updateColor(index, color) {
    modifyColor((newColors) => {
        newColors[index] = color;
    });
  }

  function deleteColor(index) {
    modifyColor((newColors) => {
        newColors.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }

  function duplicateColor(index) {
    modifyColor((newColors) => {
        newColors.splice(index, 0, newColors[index]);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that accepts a callback and returns a function that creates `newColor` and delegates that along with its arguments to the callback:

```js
function doSomethingWithColors(callback) {
  return function() {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    callback(newColors, ...arguments);
    // or callback.apply(newColors, [index, colors]);
    return newColors;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```js
function doSomethingWithColors(callback) {
  return function() {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    callback(newColors, ...arguments);
    // or callback.apply(newColors, [index, colors]);
    return newColors;
  }
}

const updateColor = doSomethingWithColors(
  (newColors, index, color) => newColors[index] = color
);

const deleteColor = doSomethingWithColors(
  (newColors, index) => newColors.splice(index, 1)
);

const duplicateColor = doSomethingWithColors(
  (newColors, index) => newColors.splice(index, 0, newColors[index])
);

const colors = ['#000', '#f00', '#fff'];

console.log(colors);
console.log(updateColor(1, '#ff0'));
console.log(deleteColor(1));
console.log(duplicateColor(1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like so

```js
const handleColors = (index, action, color = '') => {
 const newColors = [...colors];
 if (action == 'duplicate') {
    newColors.splice(index, 0, newColors[index]);
 }else if (action === 'delete') {
   newColors.splice(index, 1);
 }else {
    newColors[index] = color;
 }
    setColors(newColors);
}
```

then use it like so,

```js
handleColors(2, 'delete') // for delete
handleColors(2, 'update', 'red') // for update
handleColors(2, 'duplicate') // for duplicate
```